# Display text from one class to the GUI class

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have this code that I use to connect to a server using sockets

Client Class Code

```
public class Client {
    Socket mysocket;
    BufferedReader inFromServer;
    DataOutputStream outToServer;
    
        public Socket connect(String nameServer, int portServer) {
            try 
            {
                mysocket=new Socket(nameServer, portServer);
                outToServer=new DataOutputStream(mysocket.getOutputStream());
                inFromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mysocket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Host error"); // Display Error
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                System.out.print("Connection Error!"); // Display Error
                System.exit(1);
            }
            return mysocket;
        }
```

GUI Code

```
package Client;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class WindowClient {

    private JFrame frmSocketConnection;
    private JTextField TxtIP;
    private JTextField TxtPort;
    private JTextField TxtInput;

    Client client = new Client();
    
    public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
        if (strNum == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WindowClient window = new WindowClient();
                    window.frmSocketConnection.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public WindowClient() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmSocketConnection = new JFrame();
        frmSocketConnection.setTitle("Socket Connection");
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frmSocketConnection.setBounds(100, 100, 983, 633);
        frmSocketConnection.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBounds(725, 0, 244, 596);
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        TxtIP = new JTextField();
        TxtIP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        TxtIP.setBounds(10, 89, 224, 34);
        panel.add(TxtIP);
        TxtIP.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblIP = new JLabel("IP Address");
        lblIP.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblIP.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblIP.setBounds(10, 45, 224, 34);
        panel.add(lblIP);
        
        TxtPort = new JTextField();
        TxtPort.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        TxtPort.setColumns(10);
        TxtPort.setBounds(10, 216, 224, 34);
        panel.add(TxtPort);
        
        JLabel lblPort = new JLabel("IP Port");
        lblPort.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPort.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblPort.setBounds(10, 172, 224, 34);
        panel.add(lblPort);
        
        JButton btnConnect = new JButton("Connect");
        btnConnect.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnConnect.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        btnConnect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnConnect.setBounds(34, 317, 176, 48);
        panel.add(btnConnect);
        
        JButton btnDisconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
        btnDisconnect.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
        btnDisconnect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnDisconnect.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        btnDisconnect.setBounds(34, 396, 176, 48);
        panel.add(btnDisconnect);
        
        TxtInput = new JTextField();
        TxtInput.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        TxtInput.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        TxtInput.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        TxtInput.setBounds(10, 547, 617, 39);
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().add(TxtInput);
        TxtInput.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnEnter.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
        btnEnter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        btnEnter.setBounds(623, 547, 92, 39);
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);
        
        JTextPane TxtConsole = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = TxtConsole.getStyledDocument();
        Style style = TxtConsole.addStyle("Stile", null);
        TxtConsole.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        TxtConsole.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        TxtConsole.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        TxtConsole.setBounds(10, 10, 705, 525);
        frmSocketConnection.getContentPane().add(TxtConsole);
        
        btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                btnDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
                if (TxtIP.getText().length() == 0 || TxtPort.getText().length() == 0) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);
                    try {
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Error. One field is empty! \n",style);
                        btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
                        btnDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                else if (!isNumeric(TxtPort.getText())) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);
                    try {
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "The port field has to be a number! \n",style);
                        btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
                        btnDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.white);
                     try {
                            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Connection... \n",style);
                        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        TxtInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TxtInput.setText("");
            }
        });
        
        btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        btnDisconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TxtIP.setText("");
                TxtPort.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and I have a GUI in another class. In that class I have a JTextPane that I want to use as a "console" that display anything

[This is an image of the GUI that i have at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHMJv.png)

I want to display the error strings from the Client class into the JTextPane that it's in another class and I don't really know how to do it

Comment: how are the two classes linked?

Comment: There are most likely a dozen approaches which work: The easiest one would be to pass the UI component whose text you want to modify to your `Client` class. A cleaner approach would be to share some sort of exchanging mechanism between these two classes.  [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) with [ListChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) from Javafx may be a good option here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to communicate between data and ensure to pass it.
You can choose to throw the error/exception from `Client` class and ensure to catch  it and put that error into the `JTextPane`

I could simply try this out:

```
public static class Client {
    Socket mysocket;
    BufferedReader inFromServer;
    DataOutputStream outToServer;

    public Socket connect(String nameServer, int portServer) throws Exception {
        try
        {
            mysocket=new Socket(nameServer, portServer);
            outToServer=new DataOutputStream(mysocket.getOutputStream());
            inFromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mysocket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unknown Host Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Connection Error!"); // Display Error
            throw new Exception("Connection Error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return mysocket;
    }
}
```

A very simple version would be:

```
    Client c = new Client();
    String errorMessage = "";
    try {
        c.connect("localhost", 8010);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    }

    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setBold(attributeSet, true);

    // Set the attributes before adding text
    pane.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);

    // A very simple version of that errorMessage for illustrations only 
    pane.setText(errorMessage == null ? "Welcome" : errorMessage);
```

In your case, if you are connecting on a button action, then:

```
   btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
            btnDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
            
            // if-else
            // ...
            else {
                StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.white);
                try {

                    Client c = new Client();
                    String errorMessage = "";
                    try {
                        c.connect("localhost", 8010);
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Connecting...", style);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Setting the error Message
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), e.getMessage(), style);
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```